# Saving settings/variables/permissions in memory instead of looking them up on each API call?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, .net-4.5, api-design

I have an API set up that allows placing orders, looking up product info, reporting, etc. Each API key has specific permissions on which controllers/methods they can or can't access, as well as fields that should be omitted. Unfortunately right now I have this hardcoded in a dictionary class and would like to instead pull these permissions from a database.

The problem is I don't want to call the database to lookup permissions every time a method is called to avoid a performance hit. Is there a way to POST these settings/permissions any time there's a change (using an admin page) and have the API "remember" them in memory in some sort of dictionary? Also when restarting the API I'm guessing these are cleared so I would need a way to pull this information when the API initializes. Not sure what the best way to design this is, any suggestions are helpful thanks.

Edit: I'm avoiding roles because I have hundreds of API keys each with different settings/permissions, which I'm guessing each would need a specific role.

Comment: can you share more context of your database (is it mssql, postgres, or any other)? e.g. sql server have two technologies to detect changes:

- change tracking
- change data capture

with these you can fetch the diferential changes since the last fetch

Comment: Have you tried it with a REDIS Cache? (stands for "REmote DIctionary Service"). It is a fast, light weight service designed to store data in an in-memory remove dictionary. More you can find at [redis.io](https://redis.io). There is a password protection available to restrict access, but if you need to encrypt data you have to do it first before storing it in the cache. For C# you can use the library StackExchange.Redis.

Answer (score 3):

You can replace your dictionary with [MemoryCache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory). This is a per-instance (instance equating to a single API instantiation using, for example, a Kestrel-based self-hosted setup (likely in the cloud, but not necessarily)).

You can set the expiration time for the cache.

The above behavior would be nondeterministic across multiple instances of instantiations of your API behind a load balancer. That's not necessarily a bad thing. It is common for permissions changes to "take some time to take effect" when they change.

That said, your idea to POST the changes can avoid this latency by directly changing the entries in both the cache and database immediately (cache [write-through](https://shahriar.svbtle.com/Understanding-writethrough-writearound-and-writeback-caching-with-python) -- link is Python oriented, but the concepts are sound regardless). This means the next call to the instance gets the new values immediately from memory. *This will not survive an "API restart"*.

Why? Well, an instance has its own memory and that is wiped on a restart. To affect *all* instantiations of your API, your POST can make the changes against a *distributed* cache such as Redis, and your database (a centralized, persistent resource) immediately. This is more deterministic and survives restarts. After all, both the distributed cache and the database are persistent stores of data.

If you use [distributed caching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/distributed) for this, you just need to pick your caching's back end technology, Redis, DB, or NCache, and configure appropriately.

The key from the API implementation point of view is to try the cache first, and then try the final store... i.e. a normal caching access pattern.

Summarizing, you have two interfaces you can work from

- [IMemoryCache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.caching.memory.imemorycache)
- [IDistributedCache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.caching.distributed.idistributedcache)

and the nuances associated with each.

Finally, as for

> I would need a way to pull this information when the API initializes

This is called [cache-warming](https://www.section.io/blog/what-is-cache-warming/#:%7E:text=Cache%20warming%20is%20when%20websites%20artificially%20fill%20the,the%20first%20visitor%20to%20get%20a%20cache%20miss.) and is quite common and useful. For this I would suggest using a [background service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services), and if you really, really need cache warming to start first, check out [Running async tasks on app startup](https://andrewlock.net/running-async-tasks-on-app-startup-in-asp-net-core-3/) (it's a little dated, but still relevant). Creating this background service would read from the database and write to the cache (in-memory or distributed). In the distributed case, you may have redundant writes to the cache, but that is unlikely to be a real problem).

Answer (score 0):

can't you just use standard roles based authorization?

this is what I followed when I set mine up  https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2021/Mar/09/Role-based-JWT-Tokens-in-ASPNET-Core

```
  [Authorize(Roles = "admin")]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post(RoomDelegate roomDelegate) =>
     HandleResult(await Mediator.Send(new Post.Command { RoomDelegate = roomDelegate }));
```

store your roles in the tokens claims.

```
   public class TokenService
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration _config;
        private readonly UserManager<AppUser> _userManager;
        public TokenService(IConfiguration config, UserManager<AppUser> userManager)
        {
            _config = config;
            _userManager = userManager; 
        }

        public IConfiguration Config { get; }

        public async Task<string> CreateToken(AppUser user)
        {
            var claims = new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName ),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, user.Email),
            };

            var roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);

            foreach (var role in roles)
            {
                claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role));
            }

         

            var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_config["TokenKey"]));
            var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha512Signature);
            var tokenDescription = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
            {
                Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(claims),
                Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(10),
                SigningCredentials = creds
            };

            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescription);

            return tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);


        }

        public RefreshToken GenerateRefreshToken()
        {
            var randomNumber = new byte[32];
            using var rng = RandomNumberGenerator.Create();
            rng.GetBytes(randomNumber);
            return new RefreshToken { Token = Convert.ToBase64String(randomNumber) };   
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have hundreds of API keys each with different settings/permissions, wouldn't I have to create a role for each one?

Comment: @JoeDefill you can create a bunch of roles based on your business requirements (settings, permissions), token service is just mapping key to set of roles, nothing more, it doesnt create unique role each time, it is using predefined set to create subset of roles and encrypt it. Authenticated user then can use this token to access your API, your API decrypts token and decide whether user authorized to perform action or need to refresh it if something changed from last time (you have full control over token lifetime).

Answer (score 0):

You could store the dictionary of API Keys and their permissions as a global variable (which would be stored in memory) accessible across all classes for quick access.

The admin page would then be updating your database with the new API Keys and their corresponding permissions.

Finally, you can have a background service that periodically (Let's say every 10 seconds which i guess is better than calling your database on every http request that hits your API) picks the API key data from the DB and updates your public variable.

Below is some sample code for a background service that i have used before in a .NET 6.0 minimal API:

```
namespace Project.BackgroundServices
{
    public class RefreshAPIKeyData : BackgroundService
    {
        public static string[] apiKeyData;
        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                //call your DB and update your apiKeyData variable
                await Task.Delay(10000, stoppingToken);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can then register your background service like so in **Program.cs**

```
builder.Services.AddHostedService<RefreshAPIKeyData>();
```

And then just access your data like so:

```
string[] currentApiKeyData = RefreshAPIKeyData.apiKeyData
```

When your API is restarted, the background service will be one of the first things to run and your global variable will be up to date more or less immediately.